# How can I import this csv with some quoted lines into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I have a csv with a structure like this:

```
project, location, badness
foo, N/A, 0
bar, 'path/to/file:[7,23]', 120
```

I want to import this into a Pandas dataframe. When I use `pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar="'", sep=".\s+")` right now, I get columns like:

```
project   location           badness
foo       N/A                0
bar       'path/to/file:[7   23]'       120
```

with the final dangling column unnamed.

How can I import this in a way that respects the quotes? That is, how can I get the "location" column to have `'path/to/file:[7,23]'` on the second line?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with pandas 2.1.3 so check you version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the separator to `",\s+"`:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

text = """\
project, location, badness
foo, N/A, 0
bar, 'path/to/file:[7,23]', 120"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), quotechar="'", sep=r",\s+", engine="python")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  project               location  badness
0     foo                    NaN        0
1     bar  'path/to/file:[7,23]'      120
```

Comment: The raw string on the separator is what fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`quotechar="'"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) to specify that fields can be quoted with single quote, and [`skipinitialspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) to ignore the spaces after commas.

```
pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
```

There's no need to specify the separator.